# Using SVG inside doxygen

Tags: svg, doxygen

I am trying to add an SVG to my doxygen documentation.

First try was using `\image blabla.svg`.  This kinda worked... but, the SVG contains another  png reference, and the "internal" png was not showed. This works on Chrome, but even on Firefox this is not working.

Reading on, I see that I can use `<embed>` or `<iframe>` on tye markup. I am not sure if this is possible using doxygen.

How can I use an SVG inside my doxygen documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... one option, is to render the SVG to PNG and embbed it into doxygen "normally". This can be done using "convert" from imagemagick.

(ugly solution, waiting for a better one)

Answer (score 2):

... another option...

```
\htmlonly
<div align='center'>
<embed src="blabla.svg" width="900px" height="600px" type="image/svg+xml"     pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/" />
</div>
\endhtmlonly
```

Comment: I stumbled on this answer trying to figure how to set the size of an svg. This is answered in another question https://stackoverflow.com/q/15975262/987623