# How to specify image size in HTML Doxygen?

Tags: documentation, doxygen, image-resizing

I am trying to manually specify the image size in the HTML generated by Doxygen. However, as I read in the [documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdimage), this can only happen if using LaTeX output. Anybody here knows any workaround?

As an example, I would like to do something like this:

```
\image html example.png "Caption" width=10px
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Put this in the CSS file "Doc/doxygen_html_style.css":

```
div.image img[src="example.png"]{ 
    width:100px; 
}
```

And set the Doxygen config variable *HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET* to "Doc/doxygen_html_style.css"

Comment: Be sure to edit HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET and not HTML_STYLESHEET, I did the latter, and that disrupted the style for the whole documentation.

Answer (score 15):

Apparently, something changed over the years, because in Doxygen 1.8.17 it works almost the way it is described in the original question (no CSS involved):

```
\image html some.png width=800px
```

---

Edit: just tried this with Doxygen 1.8.13 and it also works quite well:

```
\image html some.png width=50%
```

Comment: Adjust the size by percentage is the best. In my opinion Doxygen is to improve the efficiency. Simpler the better!

Answer (score 14):

To avoid resorting to an extra CSS style sheet you can directly inline the CSS code:

```
\htmlonly <style>div.image img[src="test.png"]{width:100px;}</style> \endhtmlonly 
@image html test.png "Caption"
```

even better create an alias in Doxygen configuration file:

```
ALIASES = imageSize{2}="\htmlonly <style>div.image img[src=\"\1\"]{\2}</style>\endhtmlonly"
```

and then use this new and shorter Doxygen command:

```
@imageSize{test.png,height:270px;width:20px;}
@image html test.png "Caption"
```

Comment: Building on this answer one can make a single alias that sets the style and add the image as well:
    ALIASES = imageSize{3}="\htmlonly <style>div.image img[src=\"\1\"]{\2}</style>\endhtmlonly \image html \1 \"\3\""

Comment: Be sure to define the ALIASES in the `Doxyconf` file to avoid `Found unknown command  \imageSize`