# Doxygen: How to embed images on main page for all output formats?

Tags: html, image, markdown, doxygen

I am using Doxygen 1.8.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 to generate API documentation from C/C++ header files.

I have a main page in markdown format (file `mainpage.md`) and want to embed an image (file `logo.png`) into that page.

Currently, I have that working for HTML output, with the following directory structure:

```
    work
    ├── mainpage.md
    ├── resources
    │   └── logo.png
    └── html
        └── index.html
```

The way the markdown in `mainpage.md` embeds the image, is:

```
![The Logo](../resources/logo.png)
```

This works, but it depends on the fact that the HTML output directory is one level down from the work directory, and (fwiw) that is not in sync with the location of the `mainpage.md` file containing that reference.

I have to admit that I did not try out what happens with other output formats
(intended formats are: HTML, PDF via LaTex, man pages, Eclipse help), but 
they may work differently w.r.t. their output directory and the reference to the image file.

My questions are:

1. Do the above mentioned other output formats work with this markdown reference?
2. Is there a more output format agnostic way for referencing the image file from the main page markdown?

Andy

Comment: Did you have a look at IMAGE_PATH = resources and ![The Logo](logo.png)  for the HTML version? and at the @image command?

Comment: Please have also a look at the documentation n the chapter about Markdown and its implementation in doxygen: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/markdown.html

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately you need multiple image commands to make this work.  Latex will require a pdf compatible image type, web browsers usually require a different image type, etc., so the [image command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdimage) must be issued multiple times to specify the image file for each format

```
\image html logo.png
\image latex logo.eps
```

The following formats are supported:  html, latex, docbook and rtf.

You can use shorter paths if you put your images in an image folder and specify it's location in your [configuration](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_image_path):

```
IMAGE_PATH     = my_image_dir
```

Comment: Is it possible to resize an image when linked through Markdown?

Comment: for latex or html?  For html: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975262/how-to-specify-image-size-in-html-doxygen

Comment: for latex sizing see Doxygen documentation for `\image`  https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmdimage

Comment: Not sure if that is controllable with docbook or rtf formats.

Comment: I'd like to be able to resize an image embedded in a doxygen Markdown document. Something like `![The Logo](../resources/logo.png =100x20)`.  I would then have Doxygen output to HTML.

Comment: Read the above answer and comments.

Comment: The link in the configuration has stopped working; still a useful answer; upvoted.

Comment: here is the new link: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdimage

Comment: Yeah, sorry, had a copy/paste error when updating one of those links.  Thanks!