# Doxygen \image tag size specification syntax

Tags: doxygen

The doxygen `\image` tag documentation specifies that both `height` and `width` attributes can be given yet only the first attribute is accepted.  The second attribute is output to the resultant XML as descriptive text.

I would like to specify both image attributes as:

`\image rtf myimage.png width=100px height=250px`

The link to the documentation where it states that both attributes are permitted is: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdimage

Note the relevant section says: "The sizeindication can specify the width or height to be used (or a combination)."  What I want to know is: what is the correct syntax?  Or, is the documentation in error?

Comment: I've just pushed a proposed patch to github to include the height as well in the XML output, pull request #6424

Comment: In the mean time the pul request has been added to master on github.

Answer (score 0):

I think the

> This can be useful for LaTeX or docbook output (i.e. format=latex or format=docbook).

statement might actually mean that it is only useful with those formats. I am unable to get the width/height working myself, and even though it seems to parse the first sizeindicator argument, it does not actually use it.

Theres some old documentation available [here](https://www.star.bnl.gov/public/comp/sofi/doxygen/commands.html#cmdimage) that seems to imply that it used to only work for Latex

> This is only useful for LaTeX output (i.e. format=latex). The sizeindication can be either width or height. The size should be a valid size specifier in LaTeX (for example 10cm or 6in or a symbolic width like \textwidth).

Also the few posts online I could find regarding this:

[Here](http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/specify-image-size-td2827.html)

[and here](http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/Feature-enhancement-to-image-tag-td5404.html)

lead me to believe this is not working outside Latex formats.

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975262/how-to-specify-image-size-in-html-doxygen) might be the only working way to achieve what you want.

Edit:

After looking into the parser code within `defaultHandleTitleAndSize` in [docparser.cpp](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/master/src/docparser.cpp) which is called for `\image`, it will in fact only handle the first width or height attribute, after which it will stop.

Comment: Thank you.  It appears the documentation is incorrect.