# svg image files in doxygen

Tags: svg, doxygen

I want to include an svg image file in doxygen documentation.

I am using  the command

```
\image ./pics/gnu_lic/gplv3_logo.svg
```

However I cannot see the image

```
.
├── dox
├── Doxyfile
└── pics
    ├── gbehistun.png
    ├── gnu_lic
    │   ├── agplv3_logo.png
    │   ├── agplv3_logo.svg
    │   ├── gfdl_logo.svg
    │   ├── gplv3_logo.png 
    │   └── gplv3_logo.svg
    └── meidum
        └── tridim_latis.png
```

Comment: Dup?  Helpful?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809329/using-svg-inside-doxygen

Comment: There is not much information in there. I want to use the `svg` file rather than convert to `png` if I can. I would not want to call any Adobe stuff either.

Comment: I might have some problem with the path as well as I have tried to display a `png` and am getting the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things one has to do.

First set `IMAGE_PATH`. In my case I used `pics`. Then my `\image` commands should be changed to be

```
/// \image html gplv3_logo.png
/// \image html gplv3_logo.svg
```

This will get the images displayed.